# How to get Hosted Zone Nameservers using the AWS JAVA SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I am using the AWS Java SDK to retrieve Hosted Zone details, I don't see any method in the [AmazonRoute53Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53Client.html) class to list nameservers. I found that there is a method [ListReusableDelegationSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53Client.html#listReusableDelegationSets--), and the DelegationSet class has a [getNameServers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/DelegationSet.html#getNameServers--) method, but I think that method wont list default nameservers for Hosted Zones created using the AWS web console.

Do you know any method to achieve this?

Comment: Does `listResourceRecordSets()` include NS records? I haven't tried it so don't know, but that's the method I'd expect to use.

Comment: No, listResourceRecordSets() lists the DNS records within the hosted zone.

Comment: and as I mentioned in my comment, I would expect those to include `NS` records, which identify a set of nameservers. To be very specific, you would need to match an `NS` record with the `SOA` record to avoid nameservers for sub-domains. But it appears that there's an easier way.

Comment: Yes, thank you! There is an NS record containing the nameservers in the value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the nameservers by using the [`getHostedZone`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53Client.html#getHostedZone-com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.GetHostedZoneRequest-) method. Example:

```
AmazonRoute53 client = AmazonRoute53ClientBuilder.standard().build();
GetHostedZoneRequest request = new GetHostedZoneRequest().withId("Z3M3LMPEXAMPLE");
GetHostedZoneResult response = client.getHostedZone(request);
```

Now, from the `GetHostedZoneResult` response, we can use [`getDelegationSet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/GetHostedZoneResult.html#getDelegationSet--) method to retrieve a `DelegationSet`, from which using the [`getNameServers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/DelegationSet.html#getNameServers--) method we can retrieve a list with the 4 assigned nameservers.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was looking into HostedZone class.